# Como acessar um banco de dados usando C

Tags: mysql, c

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de acessar um banco de dados em C?

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem C não cria bancos de dados, mas você pode acessar vários bancos de dados através de bibliotecas já existentes, por exemplo:

- [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/)
- [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/)
- [LMDB++](http://lmdbxx.sourceforge.net/)